# Вызов конструктора базового класса из наследника

Tags: c++, классы, наследование, конструктор, конструктор-копирования

Привет, есть такая непонятная (для меня) ситуация:

Допустим я реализовал класс строки : String (включает практически все стандартные операции)

А теперь я хочу наследовать от него и сделать класс к примеру Specific_String в конструкторе которого определяю следующее (s - const char*):

```
if (check(s,strlen(s)) == true) {
    String(s);
}
else {
    String();
}
```

Собственно я хочу чтобы вызывались разные конструкторы для разных случаев... а вызывается только конструктор который String().

И ещё в догонку, так как я строкой не буду владеть напрямую, то как для класса реализовать конструктор копирования ?

Comment: Как вариант есть решение без использования второго конструктора. Просто изначально в списке инициализации указываем :String(s) а в теле метода пишем if(check(s,strlen(s)) != true) clear(); //вызов базового метода очищения строки...

Comment: На счет конструктора копирования я хз правильно сделал но вроде все работает. Опять же в списке инициализации :String(other){} где other - Specific_String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конструктор базового класса будет всегда вызываться раньше. Можно реализовать *сложный* конструктор, но с побочными вызовами деструкторов.

```
class Mother{
public:
Mother(){}
Mother(Mother cont & ){конструктор копирования}
};

class Son:public Mother{
public:
Son(char const * );
Son(Son const & s):Mother(s){копирование только данных son}
};

Son::Son(char const * s):Mother(){
  this->~Mother();
  if(...) new (this)Mother(s);
  else new (this)Mother();}
```

Всё будет работать, но этот приём НЕ-СТАНДАРТ.

Comment: Интересно получилось, спасибо )

Comment: Культурно все делают минимальный конструктор. Затем функцию задавания значений типа Set.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто иметь функцию установки значений по умолчанию, и в конструкторе  Specific_String вызвать эту функцию, если не выполняется условие:
Для наглядности, напишем хотябы такую ерунду:

```
class String {
    const char* arr;
    size_t size;
public:
    String() : arr("default"), size(7) {}
    String(const char* m ) : arr(m), size(strlen(m)) {}
    String(const String& str) : arr(str.arr), size(str.size){}
    ~String() { delete arr; }
    void def_data() {arr = "default"; size = 7;}
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const String& str)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size; ++i)
            os << str.arr[i];
        return os;
    }
};
class Specific_String : public String  {
    bool check(const char* m, size_t sz) { return (sz > 1 && sz <= strlen(m)); }
public:
    Specific_String(const char* s ) : String(s) { if(!check(s, strlen(s))) def_data();}
};
```

т.е. если указатель содержит адрес одного символа, то устанавливаются значения по умолчанию

```
int main()
{   
    Specific_String  str("check"), def_str("s");
    cout << str << endl << def_str;
    return 0;
}
```

в результатае получим `"check"`  и  `"default"`( а не `"s"`)